# On EC2 Windows Server 2016, automatically mount instance storage when restarting the instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016, amazon-instance-store

**I have an AWS EC2 instance based on an Amazon-provided AMI for Microsoft Windows Server 2016.** I want to use the ephemeral Instance Storage. When I Start the instance, I can login and use the Window's Disk Management tool to mount my Instance Storage as a drive letter.

However, if I Stop and then Start the instance, the Instance Storage is no longer mounted when I login. I must again use the Window's Disk Management tool to remount the Instance Storage every time I restart the instance.

**How can I make the Instance Storage appear as a drive automatically?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FYI here is a simpler solution based on the [AWS EC2 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html#ec2launch-download)

Run the following from a PowerShell window.

```
    #initial disk 1st time: 
    C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeDisks.ps1


    # schedule initial disk 
    C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeDisks.ps1 -Schedule
```

Comment: You need to run PowerShell as an administrator for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

Configure the Amazon-provided script `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeDisks.ps1` to run when the system boots.

1. Log in as Administrator.
2. Create a temporary XML file with the contents shown below.
3. Start the Windows Task Scheduler. (Start >> Administrative Tools >> Task Scheduler)
4. Select *Actions*,  *Import Task...*
5. Select your temporary XML file.
6. Press OK to create the task.

*Amazon Ec2 Launch - Initialize Disks.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <URI>\Amazon Ec2 Launch - Initialize Disks</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <BootTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </BootTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>0</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/C C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeDisks.ps1"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I figured this out with clues from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/common-issues.html#init-disks-win2k16)

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly on our Windows 2016 base AMI, always mounts Ephemeral/Internal disk as `Z:` - for those that are not experienced win admins you may want to add that the Task Scheduler is found with **Start >> Windows Administrator Tools >> Task Scheduler**